# Одновременная отправка текстовых полей и файла

Tags: python, html, post, form, request

Есть такая форма:

```
<form action="{{ url_for('admin.team_add') }}" method="POST" class="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="form_item"><div>Название</div>
                <input type="text" name="name" class="" required>
            </div>

            <div class="form_item"><div>Учебное заведение</div>
                <input type="text" name="school" class="" required>
            </div>

            <div class="form_item"><div>Токен для входа</div>
                <input type="text" name="token" class="" required>
            </div>

            <div class="form_item"><div>Гостевая</div>
                <input type="checkbox" name="is_guest" class="is_guest">
            </div>
            
            <div class="form_item"><div>Иконка команды</div>
             <input type="file" name="img" class="">
            </div>

            <div class="form_item">
                <button type="submit" class="add">Добавить</button>
            </div>

        </form>
```

При наличии `enctype="multipart/form-data"` я не могу обработать текстовые поля на стороне сервера, а без него не могу сохранить файл, есть предложения как это можно реализовать?
На стороне сервера Phyton